# Passing in a list of ids to several queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have serveral queries that use the same ids in a where clause. Currently I have

query 1

```
select * from X ....... where id in (1,2,3);
```

query 2

```
select * from Y ....... where id in (1,2,3);
```

etc etc

What I would like to have is

query 1

```
DEFINE VAR LIST;
VAR = (1,2,3)
select * from X ....... where id in (MY_VAR);
select * from Y ....... where id in (MY_VAR);
```

This will mean if I change ids I wont have to update in two places.

I tried the above but it errors. What's up with my syntax?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Plus, SQL Developer etc.:

```
SQL> define list = 1,2,3
SQL> select * from x where id in (&list.);

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
```

Comment: perfect thans. I have lots of ids. As a suplimentary question how do I split the define over two lines? Is this possible? Thanks for your help

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12017.htm) suggests that you can by putting "-" at the end of the line, but it didn't work when I just tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

```
WITH list_values AS (
     SELECT TO_NUMBER(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('1,2,3', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))) AS id
       FROM dual
    CONNECT BY INSTR('1,2,3', ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
) SELECT x.* FROM x, list_values
   WHERE x.id = list_values.id;
```

It might be worthwhile to take the subquery above and use it to create a temporary table, then simply use that table moving forward. Among other things it would allow you to have more than 1000 ids in your list.